# PHP Find right value for x when x + 20% = 276

Tags: php, for-loop

I need to be able to solve the x value from x + 20% = y with this script. The y value is already known in the script, so the x needs to be solved.

I've tried to do this with for loop.

The echo $i should output 230, but at the moment the script just doesn't return anything (Blank white screen)

```
$amount = 276;
for($i = 1; $i<300; $i++) {
    if($i+20% == $amount) {
        echo $i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basic math not a programming problem.

Comment: ^It's a programming problem, his issue is that a variable isn't display (that is what he expected)

Comment: Not really @seanyt123 - he just needs to figure out how to do the math.

Comment: @seanyt123 outside of the for loop. $amount = 276;

Comment: How do you know to use 300 as the iterator? What if the amount changes?

Comment: Basic maths: if _(x/100)*120 = y_, then _x = (y/120)*100_. Therefore, no need to loop, just calculate `$i` right off the bat (see my answer)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Maybe he needs to output all the different iterations calculated.

Comment: @TomKriek: that's what `range` is for: compute `$i`'s final value, then use `range(1, $i);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard The amount is always smaller than 300. The $amount is there just as a placeholder for this question, it changes too depending on the amount from the MySQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic maths: simply calculate 120% of value `$i`:

```
if (($i/100)*120 == $amount)
```

Or better still, calculate the value for `$i` if you know the value for 120%:

```
$i = ($amount/120)*100;
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
$i = ($amount/12)*10;
//same goes for the first snippet:
if (($i/10)*12 == $amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$amount = 276;
for($i = 1; $i<300; $i++) {
    if( ($i*=1.2) == $amount) {
        echo $i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: if the amount is found, you really should `break`, to continue the loop doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

```
$amount = 276;
for($i = 1; $i<300; $i++) {
    if($i *1.20 == $amount) {
        echo $i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the math: x + 20% = y is equal to x = y - 0.20 as the percent sign is equivalent to times 0.01 (thats why 100% == 1)

Regarding the code you posted: If i try to run the code, i get the error:

```
 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL in ...
```

The problem is the % sign -  which is in php the module operator, which needs to arguments, e.g.    `echo 4%3` which prints 1, as the rest of the integer division 4 devided by 3 is 1.

so, as already mentioned, you need to compare $x * 1.2 with $y:

```
$amount = 276;
for($i = 1; $i<300; $i++) {
if($i*1.20 == $amount) {
      echo $i;
   }
}
```